# Objective c handle adding child view controller or remove from parent

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, dealloc

I have a small question about UIViewController.

Is it possible to handle, in a custom UIViewController class, when the controller is added to current view controller using

```
[self addChildViewController:customViewController];
```

or when removing

```
[customViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

For now, I have done what I want using viewDidLoad and dealloc methods but I was wondering if there were a better solution.

Thanks,

Comment: use arc don't dealloc manually ..

Comment: I don't want to dealloc manually, I wan't to perform an action when before the object is released ..

Comment: How about performing your methods using willAppear and willDisappear on your customViewController? You could also check didMoveToParentViewController

Comment: I agree with @Teffi that probably you may just use viewWillAppear/Disappear in most cases.
I usually load static content (initializing, formatting and connecting views) in the viewDidLoad and dynamic content (data initialization) in the viewWillAppear if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller can override this method when it wants to react to being added to a container.

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent;
```

As by [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmovetoparentviewcontroller?language=objc)

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must
>   call the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view
>   controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or,
>   if there is no transition, immediately after calling the
>   addChildViewController: method.

The correspectiv for dealloc  (which is anyway discouraged) is by [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmovetoparentviewcontroller?language=objc)

```
- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent;
```

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must
>   call the willMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view
>   controller before calling the removeFromParentViewController method,
>   passing in a parent value of nil.